# Launch bottles application from command line

Tags: wine, alma-linux, emulators

I have installed bottles for Windows application emulation.

I am trying to start an application via command line but have not been able to start the application automatically. It opens up the bottle but the application does not start and it requires a manual start.

I would like to get this to work so I can create a systemd service which launches this app on system boot. OS is AlmaLinux 8.

Here's the variation of commands I have tried.

```
flatpak run com.usebottles.bottles -b NetSync -e 'C:\windows\system32\start.exe /wait C:\Program Files (x86)\BigNet\NetSync\NetSync.exe'
flatpak run com.usebottles.bottles -b NetSync -e 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BigNet\NetSync\NetSync.exe'
flatpak run com.usebottles.bottles -b NetSync -e '/home/rlee/.var/app/com.usebottles.bottles/data/bottles/bottles/NetSync/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/BigNet/NetSync/NetSync.exe'
flatpak run com.usebottles.bottles -b NetSync -e /home/rlee/.var/app/com.usebottles.bottles/data/bottles/bottles/NetSync/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/BigNet/NetSync/NetSync.exe
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with bottles; is that a graphical thing? And, in any case: How does your systemd service file look like, where do you place it and are you running it as user or system service?

Comment: Bottles is a Windows emulator. The command I run launches the bottles application and it opens the NetSync bottle. However, I need to manually press the "Play" button to run the actual NetSync application. Once I can get this to run automatically via command, then next step is to configure it as a systemd service.

Comment: ok, but this means bottles is a graphical application, right? Because that would suggest the whole approach is a dead end.-

Comment: I run it in VNC. In the ```[Unit]``` section, I set ```After=vncserver@:1.service```.  In ```[Service]```, environment is set as ```Environment="DISPLAY=:1"```. ```ExecStart``` starts a BASH script which executes ```flatpak run --command=bottles-cli com.usebottles.bottles run -b NetSync -p NetSync```. App loads after system reboots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursory glance at the [bottles documentation](https://docs.usebottles.com/advanced/cli) (usebottles.com homepage top, "docs", CLI) suggests you should be running `bottles-cli`, instead of the graphical frontend.

So,

```bash
flatpak run --command=bottles-cli com.usebottles.bottles --help
```

points out you can run subcommands (instead of `--help`); especially, the `run` subcommand:

```
usage: bottles-cli run [-h] -b BOTTLE [-e EXECUTABLE] [-a ARGS] [-p PROGRAM]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -b BOTTLE, --bottle BOTTLE
                        Bottle name
  -e EXECUTABLE, --executable EXECUTABLE
                        Path to the executable
  -a ARGS, --args ARGS  Arguments to pass to the executable
  -p PROGRAM, --program PROGRAM
                        Program to run
```

Comment: Works. I've opted for the shorter program instead of the executable ```flatpak run --command=bottles-cli com.usebottles.bottles run -b NetSync -p NetSync```